# I need an effective excercise for wings/chest

Tags: exercise, bodybuilding, weight-gain

I need an effective exercise for chest wings.
Basically my body is normal, but my chest is almost same in width to my lower body and the belly.
I want my chest/wings to be more in width, so it becomes like v shape. Currently it seems straight.I want to gain some weight for it.

Also I need an effective exercise for lower abdominal, and abs.
Thanks in Advance.

**Edited**

Well, Currently I dont do much, just few push ups, and use dumbbells for arms. That's it. But I intend to join gym in few days.

Comment: How often do you workout? Do you have access to gym equipment? What's your fitness level? It would be nice if you edited in such information, because they can effect the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want wings (Lat muscles) the best exercise is pull ups (chin ups).  You can include rows also, but don't long to far past the standard pull up.  You can use the same pull up bar for leg tucks that will work on the lower abs.

[image: pull ups]

Comment: Good exercise for lats, but I think I would deviate from the grip in the picture. The inward grip used there tends to put emphasis on the biceps, whereas an outward grip would focus on the lats more.

Comment: @Greg - I agree, I switch from chin up to pull up to neutral position - to keep things interesting and to focus on different muscles.

Comment: Lats is what you want to accentuate.  If pull ups are too difficult for you, you can also do lat pull downs.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Meade's answer, I'd recommend doing any lift that involves a pulling motion from a wide variety of angles.   This includes

- Chinups/Pullups
- Pulldowns
- Seated Rows
- T-Bar Rows
- Dumbell Rows
- Bent over barbell rows.

However, with any pulling motion be sure you achieve a **full range of motion**.  A full range of motion here implies extending your arms to the point where you feel a stretch in your lats and pulling as far as you can to the point where your elbows/shoulders are back as far as possible (your chest should poke out broad at the end of each rep).  This ensures your lats receive the maximum amount of contraction and extension and gives them the proper work.  Otherwise your biceps may be performing a larger percentage of the lift than needed and steal from your lats.

Also, when doing bench/incline presses, your lats work at the very base of the lift when you use a full range of motion (bar/dumbells all the way down to your chest).  Be sure to push with your lats as much as possible on your initial movement up.

Comment: Thanx Whaley, It was really helpful.